# Problems with select and input in mobile broswers (especially Safari), probably due to 300ms Click Delay on Mobile Devices

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mobile-safari

I've noticed that when introducing forms to my web app and testing in iOS (iPhone) and when testing using the phone emulator in Chrome Dev Tools I have a problem with HTML inputs - especially Select tags.

When I test on a mobile device, I click the select menu and the menu options are shown then immediately hidden! I must hold the form item and then release to access the options. When using the device / phone model emulator bundled with Chrome Dev tools when I click on a select menu the options aren't shown either.

My app is written using HTML5 and AngularJS so I use `ng-click` or `ng-touch` for a lot of my functionality which removes this delay but I have issue when just trying to write/focus a text input or change/set the value of a select menu.

I've tried to rectify this by changing the value of the viewport meta tag,

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
```

This seems to help with Chrome on the device, but not Safari. It also doesn't change the behaviour with the emulator in Chrome Dev tools. Applying such a change loses the ability to zoom but I am fine with that - my question is, what can I do so we don't have the delay issue in Safari? I have thought that perhaps I could write a directive that removes the delay and apply it to all forms to capture the click event on each form item like  and  but this seems a bit of an overkill. Does any one have any other suggestions?

Many thanks in advance.

Please note that **I am not using jQuery** in my app!

Comment: One option is to not use input or select for gathering info, use type hidden for post

Comment: Have you tried looking into Touche at all? It also removes the 300ms delay, maybe it will provide a more consistent behavior across mobile browsers. 

http://benhowdle.im/touche/